# VirtualBox VERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, groups

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with virtualbox virtualbox-4.3.

After an update, I'm no longer able to start my Windows VM, which points to /dev/sda physical hard disk.
I'm getting the error message VERR_ACCESS_DENIED

I had this issue before and solved it with the following command:

`sudo chmod 666 /dev/sda`

It could be that I'm not in the group disk:

`groups
root adm cdrom sudo audio video lpadmin sambashare vboxusers ssh-allowed admin
ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw-rw- 1 root disk 8, 0 Aug 22 15:49 /dev/sda`

But I'm in the root group. To prevent this error again, should I become a member of disk?